# How to use vera++ in windows

Tags: c++, vera++

How to use vera++ in windows

Thats work, but how i change(reformate) my code in this file ?

**Screen**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEGKF.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is vague. Please specify what you want to do and what you have tried.

Comment: Shows a discrepancy between the rules, but does not fix the code in the source file.